# Centos 6.4 and UEFI

Tags: linux, centos, uefi, bios

I have centos 6.4 64. In /boot/efi/EFI/redhat I have grub.efi file (about 251Kb). However, when I execute `efibootmgr` I get

> Fatal: Couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing
>   EFI variables. Try 'modprobe efivars' as root.

My question what do I use - BIOS or UEFI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page suggests you need BIOS or a more recent version of CentOS 6: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/UEFI.